# Matching of (address) objects with spelling differences

Tags: c#, architecture, string-comparison, user-data

I import some data that includes addresses from concert venues, that were manually typed by different users. So, besides spelling errors, I also have different spellings (Strasse, Straße, Str. ...). An address record consists of:

- name (of the venue)
- street (including house number)
- city
- postalcode

My idea would be to calculate f.e. the Levinstine-Damerau-Distance between all address instances and then finding closely connected instances. Than the user should decide, if these adresses are the same and which spelling should be used.

I am a bit worried about the O(n²) when it comes to calculate the distance between all address data (5.000 plusminus).

Is my approach reasonable and what improvements are possible. Also I wonder, how the user interface when it comes to decide about doublettes could look like ...

Thanks in advance,
Frank

Comment: You may be able to justify that if it is a one off operation. I have used the Soundex algorithm before to deal with matching on user input. You can then narrow down your analysis to matching terms. Mind you, I'm not sure how well this algorithm works for non English words.